# Deleting Tags in Evernote

Tags: tags, evernote

I was wondering if there is a way to **delete tags** from a web application integrated with Evernote. I know that noteStore.expunge_tag throws a PERMISSION_DENIED exception and that Evernote doesn't give permission to permanently delete something, but I was hoping that there is another way to delete the tags (like the delete_note which moves the notes into the trash folder).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems a similar question was asked on the Evernote developer discussion forum. And the [answer](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/30678-deleting-tags/#entry165466) given by one of the employees was...

> Unfortunately no, there isn't a way to not delete permanently a tag, we do not have a function to put a tag in the trash (like we have for notes).

Sorry.